# Plasma power indicator/monitor doesn't read recharge until restart

Tags: power-management, macintosh, plasma5, battery

**Update: this is not limited to Fedora; see note at the end.**

---

When the battery is down and I have to charge the indicator doesn't show the charging progress even when the full 100% is confirmed by the led indicator turning green. If I unplug the numbers go down and eventually the system goes to sleeps as it is supposed to at the indicated low levels of battery -- when in fact it's close to 100% -- and if I restart it gets back to normal and I can see the real charge close to 100%.

Could I restart the Plasma power indicator/monitor so that I could get the correct battery level without rebooting?

[image]

### Update:

- This is not limited to Fedora, I have this now on Kubuntu 22.10, with backports PPA adding Plasma 5.26.1 with kernel 5.19.9
- It seems related to the kernel version because it was absent in Kubuntu 22.04 with an older kernel (I guess 5.15)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/battery-indicator-not-working-properly-asus-tuf-gaming-a15-fa506ih/25946

Or post it on askfedora

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423013)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Is right: if the link all of the sudden is unreachable, no one can see what the solution may be.

Comment: This is not limited to Fedora anymore (see update in question). Your link is Asus-specific and also different (auto-suspend not working; here auto-suspend is  working but the charge values displayed are  wrong). It also discusses a bug in 5.19.4 fixed in 5.19.9, while here I had 5.18.11 and now 5.19.0 The solution is to upgrade to a later kernel and l will try that.

Comment: I mean *your* solution is to upgrade the kernel, I have tried that and it didn't work. On the contrary going back to 5.15 seems to work.